# Columns messing with sidebar after switching bootstrap theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've switched themes to a blank bootstrap theme, but as the theme uses col-sm for the sidebar, my already established columns for my search results are messing with it, and the sidebar ends up on the bottom of the page.

The html for my results:

```
<div class="container">

    <?php
    $i=0;
    while ($query->have_posts())
    {
        if($i%2==0)
            echo '<div class="row">';
        $query->the_post();

        ?>

        <div class="col-md-6" >
           <div style="height:600px">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" align="middle"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                <div>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    echo '<p>';
                    the_post_thumbnail("small");
                    echo '</p>';
                }
                ?>
                </a>
                 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">   
      <div>                <?php
                echo do_shortcode('[gdrts_stars_rating_auto template="default"
                 style_type="image" style_image_name="star" alignment="right"]');
                ?>
        </div>

                <div class="metatext">
                    <span>Metascore: </span>
                </div>

                <?php
                $score = get_field('metascore'); 

                if($score < 50) {    
                  $class = "R";
                } elseif($score < 75) {
                  $class = "Y";
                } else {
                  $class = "G";
                }
                ?>


                <div class="metacontent<?php echo $class; ?>"><div><span> <?php echo $score; ?> </span></div> </div>
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                     <div class="panel-heading">
                         <h3 class="panel-title">Payment options</h3>
                     </div>
                 <div class="panel-body">
                    <?php 

                    $field = get_field_object('free');
                    $value = $field['value'];
                    $choices = $field['choices'];

                        if( $value ): ?>
                        <ul>
                        <?php foreach( $value as $v ): ?>
                        <li>
                    <?php echo $choices[ $v ]; ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                </div>


        </div>
        </div>
                <div style="clear: both;">
                    <p><br /><?php the_excerpt(); ?><p>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <?php
        if($i%2!=0)
            echo '</div>';
        $i++;
    }
    ?>

</div>
```

[Link to site](http://www.ticktickplay.com) so you can see it for yourself.

I want the sidebar to appear on the left side on desktops and on top on phone-sized devices.

Comment: There's a lot going wrong there. Containers shouldn't be nested. The sidebar column is *inside* your body column. We're not going to be able to help much considering that we can't see how you're using the template.

Comment: What do you need in order to help me?

Comment: Also, the theme puts the sidebar into my container, I have no idea why.

Comment: Some understanding of where you're putting the code you posted.

Comment: Also, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com